# How do you implement a rospy KeyboardInterrupt without killing the node?

Tags: rospy, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run a process in a while loop that prints to screen, and exit the while loop by pressing a key or 'Ctrl+C'. But I don't want the same key press to also kill the ros node - I just want to exit the loop. In python you can use `KeyboardInterrupt` like so:

```
import time     

while True:
    try:
        print 'Help! Im stuck in a while loop! Press Ctrl+C to save me!'
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

do_other_stuff()
```

But this doesn't work in a ROS node, and I assume it's because `rospy` handles the 'Ctrl+C' command in a slightly different way (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

I've tried the ROS equivalent, which replaces `KeyboardInterrupt` with `rospy.ROSInterruptException` but this doesn't work either - ROS simply never acknowledges the 'Ctrl+C' command. I've also tried checking for `rospy.is_shutdown()` in the while loop, as per [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/238857/how-to-exit-a-ros-node-on-keyboard-interrupt/). But this kills the node outright, so I can't continue running other functions or run the while loop again.

Does anyone have a way of achieving this? Or does one of my methods work but I've got the syntax wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239968/how-do-you-implement-a-rospy-keyboardinterrupt-without-killing-the-node?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy sets up an interrupt handler for SIGINT (ctrl-C), and uses that to trigger shutdown of ROS.

If you don't want rospy to shut down when your program gets SIGINT, you should pass the `disable_signals` argument to `rospy.init_node()`, as described in [rospy initialization and shutdown](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown):

```
rospy.init_node('my_node', disable_signals=True)
```

You will then be able to do your own handling of SIGINT (or `KeyboardInterrupt`).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-07-20**:
Yeap, that did the trick! As usual I read the right documentation but not thoroughly enough. The rospy exceptions still don't work, but setting `disable_signals=True` lets you deal with the interrupt as normal, just using `KeyboardInterrupt` Thanks again ahendrix!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If someone ends up here searching for how to that in ROS2 the key is:

```
rclpy.init(args=args, signal_handler_options=SignalHandlerOptions.NO)
```

don't forget import:

```
from rclpy.signals import SignalHandlerOptions
```

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minhaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/72920/minhaj/) on 2022-07-28**:
thank you!